# Magento: Url Key based catalog price rule not working

Tags: magento

I have set a catalog price rule for percentage discount. I have set two conditions for it to work

.i.e.

1. If the category 12, &
2. If the URL Key is xyz

And the url key is same as of the above category. But it does not work if I use the URL Key only or if I use both conditions. It only works if I use the condition no#1.

The url key value has been taken from the catalog-> Manage Category -> Category 12 (Url Key value)

For Example :
mydomain.com/my-category.html

I copied my-category and set it as URL KEy in catalog price rule condition. And the reason for doing is that I do not want to show discount price on products of same category on other pages.

Hope all this make sense.

Comment: The URL key is the url for your category.For example: http://domain.com/CategoryName and key values is your Category ID. You can make a rule that will work on condition having category ID = 12

Comment: The thing is that I do not want to show the discount price on other pages for same category products

Comment: I have modified the question, kindly do have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you shouldn't create discount rules based on the url key. It is very unstable.
Second, your rule does not work because the `url_key` attribute involved in the rule does not belong to the category entity. It is a product attribute.
So your discount would be applied for the products that belong to the category 12 and have the url_key `xyz`.

Comment: Then is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: Good way is don't create discount rules based on the url key

Comment: @atif. I don't think there is a way to achieve what you want. And it's  kind of immoral to give a discount to a product only if you buy it from a specific category.

Comment: Agree to you both Marius and Slimshaddyyy but we all agree that we do not code for ourselves unless and until asked to do so even if we suggest not to do it that way ;) Anyways thanks much Marius